# How to replace a text using the found expression with regex?

Tags: python, regex, grep

I have a .txt file that contains the following lines (hundreds like that) :

```
AAIT    AC Asia Information Tech MSCI Ishares
AAL     American Airlines Group Inc.
AAME    Atlantic American Corp
AAOI    Applied Optoelectronics Inc
AAON    Aaon Inc
```

I would like to replace those lines with :

```
1.AAIT
2.AAL
3.AAME
4.AAOI
5.AAON
```

How could I do it with grep, python or any program regex compatible ? What's important for me is to learn how to use the "found expression" variable in the replacement statement.

For instance I would like regex to select `AAIT`, store it into a variable, delete line 1 and write `1.AAIT` into line 1 using the variable and so on. Is it possible to do it with a regex compatible program such as grep or do you have to use a programming language such as python ? If you have to use python could you give me a hint on the functions and libraries to use that would make me able to cycle through all lines, select everything before the separator (tab) and do what I need it to do ?

Comment: Or how about *writing any code at all*?!

Comment: `/^(\w*?)\s/m` and use the capture `$1`

Comment: @thomas : what do you mean by $1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use `awk`, then it wold be:

```
awk '{print NR"."$1}' file
1.AAIT
2.AAL
3.AAME
4.AAOI
5.AAON
```

Comment: sweet it works with cygwin awk but how to print into the file directly instead of a shell response ?

Comment: to save the output of the command to a file, append `> myoutputfile.txt` to the command

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import re

str = """ AAIT    AC Asia Information Tech MSCI Ishares
AAL     American Airlines Group Inc.
AAME    Atlantic American Corp
AAOI    Applied Optoelectronics Inc
AAON    Aaon Inc """

match = re.findall(r'^(\w+)\b', str, re.MULTILINE)

print match ##['AAL', 'AAME', 'AAOI', 'AAON']
```

http://regex101.com/r/oO5wE0/1

Can't get [python fiddle](http://pythonfiddle.com/) to save the file, but you can plug that code in and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

`/^((?:AAIT|AAL|AAME|AAOI|AAON)(?:.*))/gm`

with the modifier `m` to make it multiline and be able to use `^` to match the begging of each line.

http://regex101.com/r/fD3yG9/1

Comment: the problem is you enter all the names manually but my file contains hundres of lines

Comment: @Wicelo so you want to print from the first to last line. May i provide an awk solution?

Comment: @Avinash Raj : if awk is usable with windows sure !

Comment: @Wicelo You have `gnu awk` for windows. http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm

Comment: sorry, i don't know about windows. You could simply do this in awk. See jotne's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
^(.*?)\b.*$
```

or whatever marks the word boundary in the language you are using

Answer (score 0):

A python version... This expects the file name as the argument when you call the script.

```
import sys
fname = sys.argv[1]
with open(fname,'rU') as fstream:
    for num,line in enumerate(fstream):
        # assumes tab between the ticker symbol and the rest
        # if not, use "  " instead of "\t"
        vals = line.split("\t")  
        print "{0}.{1}".format(num+1,vals[0])
```